# In Rust WASM Game of Life tutorial, can't get the mouse click event to work

Tags: node.js, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

**Problem:** Can't seem to get the mouse click toggle event working. On clicking, a live cell should turn dead and a dead cell should turn alive.

I have uploaded the Rust/WASM Game of Life tutorial project in this [Github Repo](https://github.com/arnabanimesh/wasm-game-of-life) for those who want to find the issue. PRs are welcome.

*For the ones who don't know about the tutorial, [click here](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/implementing.html) to know more.*

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Just changed the variable name from `CanvasRight` to `CanvasTop` in `www/index.js` and it is working now.